# Counting the maximum "levels" aka largest number of subfolders in a directory on a server, using mac OSX

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a server with a lot of files and folders in it. We are talking a very large number - in the thousands easily for both files and folders, probably a lot more but I haven't done a count yet.

I'll give an example of my hierarchy and then ask my question.

**Example Folders:**

```
    Starting folder-->                 
                    folder1a -->                              
                                folder2a -->
                                            folder3a 
                                                 file3a
                     folder1b -->
                                folder2b -->
                                    |       folder3b
                                    |             file3b
                                    file 2b (at the same level as folder2b)
```

Here, folder3b and folder3a are both 2 levels down from the original starting folder on the server, 'starting folder' (is levels even the right word?). I'm trying to count the **deepest** number of folders in this directory. I think I know how to count the actual folder number in the terminal - if you put in

`ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l`

It should give you the number of subdirectories in the directory specified. For example in this example folder, it should give 6 subdirectories. However I just want the deepest level - in this case the answers give the same, with 3 levels down from the starting directory for both folder 3a and 3b. So in this case I would want my code to return 3 instead of 6.

If i am also reading about the following code correctly, running:

`echo */ | wc`

Should return 2 for the number of sub-directories in a directory but doesn't count more than one level down.

Is it possible to run through the whole server and return the number that is the lowest level down? If i am thinking about this correctly, I want it to return the number of double clicks it will take me to get to the deepest folder in the server (note that I don't actually need to know the file path, just the number).

I'll happily explain myself if I'm not making as much sense as I should be.

Comment: Be precise while asking question,

Comment: I have explained myself as much as I can - I don't know what else to add without people asking me questions about the problem. have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` like this to list directories only

```
find . -type d
```

If you then pass the list of names through `awk` you can count how many fields (i.e. levels) there are if you use the directory separator (`/`) as awk's field separator

```
find . -type d | awk -F'/' '{print NF}'
```

then you can run that through `sort` to find the largest

```
find . -type d | awk -F'/' '{print NF}' | sort -rn
```

**Updated**

If you want to check that I count the same as you do, you can run this command and it will show you both the numbers of directories and all the names:

```
find . -type d | awk -F'/' '{print NF,$0}' | sort -rn
```

Comment: Sorry - I've been away from work and havent had chance to actually check. Just used this and it gave me 14 which doesn't sound right, but may well be. Does passing the names through awk still work for the directory separator if the directory names are named unusually? eg some have spaces, some special characters etc. if so then 14 is likely correct, however I'm sure i counted some manually (i had a quick flick through to get a rough idea) and thought i got to 16 aat one point and hadn't looked thorough all of the folders.

Comment: Also thank you for explaining the evolution of the terminal code - It helps a lot that you explained each part sequentuially / what it does as I'm new to unix and this chelps a lot with understanding.

Comment: I have added another version at the bottom of my answer that shows yo both the number of levels and the names of each level, if you want to check that.

Comment: Yep, looks like your code words. 14 must be right. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work for you:

```
find . -type d | sed -e s':[^/]::g' | wc -L
```

- first we search for all subdirectories and havve the path names printed
- in the pathnames (which will be like "./folder1a/folder2a") we eliminate everything but the slashes
- we use `wc` to return the longest line length, which is the maximum number of slashes, thus the maximum level of a subdirectory

Comment: I don't believe the `wc` on OS X accepts `-L` as a parameter.

Comment: @mark setchell I'm afraid that could be correct, I can't check at the moment

Comment: -L isn't accepted in OSX as mark said sadly. However I tried this without the -L and it gave me: 2851    2850   20808, which is only the maximum number of directories and not the lowest level.

Comment: `wc -L` would have printed the length of the longest line instead which would have been the maximum level